# Filter out selected values in Type odoo

Tags: python, list, listview, drop-down-menu, odoo

How can we filter the values from the tree view that are already selected. In other words I want to filter out the ids from the tree view which are already added as an item.

See this as an example.

[image]

If I have added the item with type let say 'A' then this cannot be added again.

Models

```
class res_partner(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'

    id_info = fields.One2many('identification.info', 'id_partner')


class Identification_Information(models.Model):
    _name='identification.info'

    identification_type = fields.Many2one('identification.type', string='Type')
```

xml file

```
<record id="customer_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Sample Partner</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="partner_sample.view_res_partner_form_sample_inherit"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="driver" position="replace">
            <field name="id_info" string="IDs(No Expiration)">
                <tree editable="bottom">
                    <field name="identification_type"/>
                    <field name="identification_number"/>
                </tree>
            </field>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look at the help center, in particular [how to ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried?

Comment: @Karen show your models with fields and template.

Comment: @DanilaGanchar please see codes above. thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all I don't think that this solution will be work with `editable="bottom"`.

You need add new field which will exclude id's of records for dropdown. For example I just exclude items with id = 1 and 2.

```
class Identification_Information(models.Model):
    _name='identification.info'

    identification_type = fields.Many2one('identification.type', string='Type')

    excluded_types = fields.One2Many(
        'identification.type',
        string='Excluded types',
        # here you need create custom logic or call other python method
        default=lambda self: [1, 2],
        # field not store in db
        store=False,
    )
```

Your tree:

```
<tree>
    <!-- hide field with excluded ids. This field is need because we use him in domain below -->
    <field name="excluded_types" invisible="1"/>
    <!-- set domain with ids from our custom field  -->
    <field name="identification_type" domain="[('id', 'not in', excluded_types),]"/>
    <field name="identification_number"/>
</tree>
```

This solution is good if you have a couple views for `identification.type`. And in one you need to show all items, but in second not all.

If you need to limit dropdown for all views. Just add domain to your model on field:

```
class Identification_Information(models.Model):
    _name='identification.info'

    identification_type = fields.Many2one('identification.type', string='Type', domain=[('id', 'not in', [1, 2])])
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Danila :)